# Venice (Treviso) to Ljubljana

Tags: trains, planning, buses, airport-transfer, tsf

I have a flight that arrives at Venice Treviso (TSF) Airport at 16:50. I would appreciate some suggestions of how I can get to Ljubljana. I have looked at some buses however it seems that they are too close (or before) the flight arrival. 
It also seems that the train is once daily and my flight lands after the train.

On the return I am looking for the opposite Ljubljana to Treviso. The flight leaves at 21:55. However the return trip is not much of a trouble as I would be able to catch the DRD early morning bus.

Comment: Is it an option to spend the evening in Venice and take a late train arriving in Ljubljana next morning?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo It is an option and that is what I think I will end up doing

Answer (score 3):

As is often the case for European rail route related queries, [the Man in Seat 61 has you covered](http://seat61.com/Slovenia.htm#Ljubljana-Trieste-Venice)!

The brief summary (see the [seat61 page](http://seat61.com/Slovenia.htm#Ljubljana-Trieste-Venice) for full details) is:

- Hourly regional train from Venice to Trieste
- Historic tram from Trieste Piazza Oberdan tram terminus to Villa Opicina, the Italian border town, trams every 20 minutes, probably...
- If the tram isn't working, take a taxi the whole way!
- Taxi from Villa Opicina to Sezana, 4 miles, about €12. Taxi probably needs to be pre-booked
- Local train from Sezana to Ljubljana, trains every 1-2 hours

Comment: Even if he was able to catch the train from Venezia Mestre at 17:21 (highly unlikely) which arrives in Trieste 19:16, it is almost just as impossible to get from Trieste to Sezana before the last train departs for Ljubljana at 19:50.

Answer (score 2):

There are trains from Treviso Centrale to Trieste. Check on bahn.de. You most probably wont make the last train from Sezana, so spend the night in Trieste.